# How to change logo in Larecipe v2.0 Laravel package?

Tags: laravel, package, documentation

I'm using the Laravel Larecipe package to create documentation for my site. I can't find anywhere to change the Larecipe logo in the top left hand corner to our company logo.

I'm using Larecipe v2.0.

I found the logo.blade.php file in the vendor folder, but I don't want to change it there as it will be overwritten when the next update comes out through composer.

Is there a better or more proper way to change this item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running the command:

`php artisan larecipe:install`

You should be able to find the proper file under:

`resources/views/vendor/partials/logo.blade.php`

Where you can find the logo. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks to both you and @SaleemMH

My confusion was from the difference between:

resources/views/vendor/partials/logo.blade.php
&
vendor/binarytorch/larecipe/resources/view/partials/logo.blade.php

I didn't realize that larecipe already publishes those folders for you. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Mr. @giovanni-s said.

I made `larecipe::install` command publish all the needed views under `resources/views/vendor/larecipe/partials` so you can override any view you want.

- Plus: if you want to change any other view that's not published by the command, you can just override the view in the correct working dir, see an example [here](https://github.com/saleem-hadad/larecipe/issues/97)

Regards.